# webpack bootstrap-loader will emit bootstrap.js but not bootstrap.css file?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, sass, bootstrap-loader

In a nutshell, I am trying to output my css assets using the `extract-text-webpack-plugin`. I would expect that the bootstrap loader would spit out a `bootstrap.css` but this is not the case. I'm thinking I might have to add a `include 'webpack-loader/path/to/css'` in my `app.js`, but something about that feels chintzy and against the purpose of webpack.

Below is the most minimal `webpack.config.js` I can create that represents the issue. The configuration assumes that the [`webpack.bootstrap.config.js`](https://github.com/shakacode/bootstrap-loader/blob/master/examples/basic/webpack.bootstrap.config.js) and [`.bootstraprc`](https://github.com/shakacode/bootstrap-loader/blob/master/examples/basic/.bootstraprc-3-example) files are located in the same directory as the `webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require("path");

const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const bootstrapEntryPoints = require('./webpack.bootstrap.config');

const extractCssPlugin = new ExtractTextPlugin({
    filename : '[name].css'
});

module.exports = {
    entry : {
        app : "./src/js/app.js",
        bootstrap : bootstrapEntryPoints.dev
    },
    output : {
        path : path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename : "[name].bundle.js"
    },
    module : {
        rules : [
            { test: /\.css$/, use : extractCssPlugin.extract({use : [{loader: "css-loader"}]})},
            { test: /\.(woff2?|svg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000' },
            { test: /\.(ttf|eot)$/, loader: 'file-loader' },
        ]
    },
    devServer : {
        contentBase : path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        hot : true,
    },
    plugins : [
        extractCssPlugin,
    ],
};
```

NOTES :

- `bootstrapEntryPoints.dev` resolves to `'bootstrap-loader'`. Meaning that my bootstrap entry point looks like `entry : {..., bootstrap : 'bootstrap-loader'}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution** - I set the `extractStyles` variable in the `.bootstraprc` to `true`. I can now sleep with peace.